# Azure HttpTrigger Function not scaling

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

**Updated/ReWritten!**

My first attempt at functions, ultimate aim is to use a durable function to fan out and back in again to speed up converting a PDF into single page images.

For now I'm testing performance and scaling.

Processing one PDF from multiple functions wasn't very efficient so I split my PDF into single page PDFs and then ran a second function against that, my code is as follows:

```
namespace PoC
{
    public static class SplitPDF
    {
        static string storageAccountConnectionString = "";

        [FunctionName("SplitPDF")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("SplitPDF HTTP trigger function received a request.");

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            Aspose.Pdf.License pdfLicense = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
            pdfLicense.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("functest");
            CloudBlockBlob pdfBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Azure Machine Learning Essentials.pdf");

            Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfFileEditor pdfEditor = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfFileEditor();

            var index = 1;
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await pdfBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(inStream);
                while (index < 238) {
                    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        int[] pagesToExtract = new int[] { index };
                        pdfEditor.Extract(inStream, pagesToExtract, outStream);
                        outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        CloudBlockBlob outBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"page_pdf/{index}.pdf");
                        await outBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(outStream);
                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            log.Info($"SplitPDF Took {stopwatch.Elapsed}.");
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
    public static class GenPageImage
    {
        static string storageAccountConnectionString = "";

        [FunctionName("GenPageImage")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("GenPageImage HTTP trigger function received a request.");

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            int page = Convert.ToInt32(req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "page", true) == 0)
                .Value);

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("functest");

            CloudBlockBlob pdfBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"page_pdf/{page}.pdf");
            CloudBlockBlob imageBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"page_png/{page}.png");

            Aspose.Pdf.Devices.Resolution resolution = new Aspose.Pdf.Devices.Resolution(96);
            Aspose.Pdf.Devices.PngDevice device = new Aspose.Pdf.Devices.PngDevice(resolution);

            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await pdfBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(inStream);
                var doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(inStream);

                using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    device.Process(doc.Pages[1], outStream);
                    outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    await imageBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(outStream);

                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            log.Info($"GenPageImage Took {stopwatch.Elapsed}.");
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a random Azure PDF of 237 pages, the split takes 18s, I then run:

```
for (( i=1; i<=237; i++)); do wget -b -q "http://url/api/GenPageImage?page=$i"; done
```

I have App Insights and live streaming and the whole process to convert the 237 single page PDFs takes 2 minutes, each one should take no more than a few seconds. Throughout the whole process the CPU sits at 100% but it never scales up.

The documentation says on a consumption plan it should scale out based on the number of incoming requests, is 200+ not enough?

I added a 3rd function to just create all the images in a single function and that also took about 2 mins :-(

NB: the image generation can be done without an Aspose license but the extraction will only give you the first 4 pages so if you want to try it then maybe just copy the first few pages multiple times to generate the volume.

**Update after adding suggested scale setting:**

Hope this info helps.

After adding the setting the function started up again with 3 instances, I let these die off till there were 0 then sent the split file request, the cold start was about 10s for info.

With 1 instance running I then submitted the 237 requests and what I saw was:

Start sending HTTP Requests - 09:01:23

Images appear in output folder (based on modified date of files):

```
09:01:57 to 09:02:01 - 60 pngs
09:02:34 to 09:04:38 - 119 pngs
09:04:50 to 09:04:51 - 58 pngs
```

During the 20-30s gaps no content was generated, I watched the nodes scale from 1 to 3 almost straight away then there was a long gap of inactivity then a 4th node appeared and seemed to start processing content while the others had been dormant for a good few seconds. Start to finish the whole process took even longer than before at 3m 28s.

With 4 instances running I then tried again:

Start sending HTTP Requests - 09:09:44

Images appear in output folder (based on modified date of files):

```
09:09:45 to 09:10:17 - 178 pngs
09:10:55 to 09:11:09 - 59 pngs
```

This time all 4 instances were busy then there was a bit of a lull and a 5th started up and appeared to finish things off which I think explains the nearly 40s gap in processing? Start to finish now was better at 1m 25s although still barely faster than a single instance doing them all.

At this point I'm wondering if I should jump straight into the Durable function fan out approach under the assumption the scaling in that might be better?

Comment: could you please share the function code ?

Comment: @Thomas I was coding late at night and tired and hadn't done my usual due diligence, going to try and distil this to a simpler example that I can share with a bit more useful diagnostic info later today, thanks.

Comment: With your design, the function might experience spikes when handling large file. To avoid, you may want to consider using Queue-Based Load to queue your file to run asynchronously. That said, instead of Blob trigger, the implementation would use Queue trigger whose message contains file location which Function needs to process. And if you need sequential ordering, go with Azure Service Bus Queue.

Comment: Updated with a bit more meat on the bone and effort on my part!

Comment: @ThuanNg Yeah large file processing wasn't a good idea architecturally!

Comment: Please try `WEBSITE_HTTPSCALEV2_ENABLED=1` and see if it helps (see [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/90) for more info). But things will get yet better and no longer require this flag in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @DavidEbbo - Thanks for the info, see my update with findings based on using that setting

Comment: The trouble with queues is that they use polling, which generates costs even when they should be idle (in my opinion this seems to go against the intent of consumption plan pricing)... around 150,000 requests per day for an empty, idle queue.

Comment: @Simon if you can share the app name and UTC time of your run, we can take a look at what happened on the scaling side.

Comment: @DavidEbbo App is at https://axpdf2png.azurewebsites.net (currently turned off) and the times in my update are UTC times so just after 9AM today, cheers.

Comment: @Simon we will take a look and get back to you

Comment: Initial finding is that while the new scale behavior helps a bit, it still struggles to handle scenarios that are CPU intensive, and where the load quickly goes from zero to high. @chrisgillum may be able to advise as to whether Durable Functions would be a good approach for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to ask if I go the durable function fan out approach whether this would improve the handling?